# is this use of jstl is correct? why it does not work?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

in netbeans 7 and jdk 7 and everything is working fine without any changes i made in my environment the old tags are working fine of jstl ${class.get_name()}
${page.getTitle()}

the new once i introduce does not work, and i don't know why ?

see this simple application example i created added jstl 1.2 into the libraries

and still it does not work?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <% 
        String var1;
        var1 = "Welcome";
        %>
        normal : <%=var1%>
        <hr />
        dollar: ${var1}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "does not work". What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the above page doesn't even use the JSTL. It uses the JSP EL.

And I assume you expect to see `dollar: "Welcome"` printed, but that won't happen, because the JSP EL doesn't print values of local variables. It prints the value of attributes.

Change your code to

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("var1", "Welcome"); %>
```

or, better, to

```
<c:set var="var1" value="Welcome"/>
```

and you'll see the expected output.